# iPhone UIWebView blanks with special characters on URL

Tags: iphone, ios, character-encoding, uiwebview

Simple thing I'm doing is connecting to retrieving user's name from Facebook and passing it to a web site as a parameter in the form of:

http://website.com?name=

However ios's UIWebView fails being able to load the url if the name has special characters used commonly in foreign names: Such as this one [fb link](http://graph.facebook.com/dogdemir)

I retrieve the title, keep it in an NSString and pass it and append it to the URL.

What do you think can be the cause and how can I possibly fix it? I am fine with the name appearing incorrectly or with special characters encoded with numbers but it just fails.

Anyone came across this?

Thanks!

Comment: What special characters are you referring it? What are the special characters in "http://www.facebook.com/dogdemir" ?

Comment: it shows Dogan as Do\u011fan where g is silent with the accent on top. When I try to view this in xcode console I get -D-o-g-a-n and when I use it in a URL parameter it is confused totally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try encoding URL encoding the parameter. Just google for "ios encode url", ir this link http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios